# Adding event as parameter within function, using addEventListener (Doesn't work in Firefox/IE)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FML</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function function1(e, div) {
div.innerHTML="this works"
document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML= 'x-pos on click: ' + e.clientX
div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){test(event, this)}, true);
}

function test(e, div) {
div.innerHTML+='<br/>so does this'
//This doesn't work. Can't add event as a parameter to function that has to be executed when using addEventListener
document.getElementById('myspan2').innerHTML= 'y-pos on move: ' + e.clientY
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="myspan">&nbsp;</span>
<span id="myspan2">&nbsp;</span>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;overflow:hidden;"  onclick="function1(event, this)">
</body>
</html>
```

Click on the blue div.

I want to add the event `mouseover`, have it execute the `test()`-function which should contain following parameters: this, event

When the function `test(e, div)` is called I keep getting an "event is undefined" error in Firefox and IE, although ironically enough it works perfectly in Chrome and Safari.

Any way I can add the event parameter by using `addEventListener`? I can get it to work with `window.event` in Chrome and Safari, but this is the exact setup that I want. I've been googling and trial/erroring for a while now, without success... so FML :/ Any tips/hints/... besides shooting myself in the head?

I know jQuery would probably solve all this, but I want to be proficient in Javascript before migrating to jQuery. Or should I migrate anyway?

Comment: Besides my answer, thumbs up for "I know jquery would probably solve all this, but I want to be proficient in javascript before migrating to jQuery." This is the right way to learn a language. And it seems rare in JS community. Because I've seen people, here in SO, who were even asking for a special construct in jQuery to be made to substitute if-then-else... :-D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){test(event, this)}, true);
```

Well, of course you get "event is undefined" ! When the `mousemove` event triggers, your event handler is called:

```
function(){test(event, this)}
```

There are two ways to reach the event information object. Either it is passed to the event handler as an argument, or it can be found in `window.event`.

Suppose the second case holds. As there is no local variable named `event` in your function, nor is there such variable in `function1` that calls it, the browser looks if there is an `event` defined in the global object. In JavaScript, the global object is called `window`, so your function is interpreted as

```
function(){test(window.event, this)}
```

and it works.

However, as I noted before, in some browsers, the event information is passed in the argument. So your event handler probably wanted to look like this:

```
function(event){test(event, this)}
```

otherwise the `event` passed to `test()` would be undefined. So, this is how to make a cross-browser handler:

```
function(event) {
  if (!event) // i.e. the argument is undefined or null
      event = window.event;

  test(event, this);
}
```

The second problem is that `addEventListener()` doesn't work in older IEs (it does in IE9, though). For older IEs, you have to use a similar function called `attachEvent()`. Or, if you only attach one handler, you can do it the simple way

```
div.onmousemove = function() {...};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks ! This was bothering me for way too long, never thought this would ever get solved. Seems like you're a purist :) I've migrated to jQuery in the meanwhile though, but I still (luckily) use JavaScript for the smaller stuff so I don't have to load an entire (jQuery) library.

Comment: Can the event listener be removed with this approach? Otherwise what is the point of nesting a named function inside an anonymous function in this way?

Answer (score 2):

In some browsers like Firefox the **event** has to be passed as a parameter, so you have to replace this code

```
div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){test(event, this)}, true);
```

with this

```
div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){test(event, this)}, true);
```

Compare carefully the two lines of code and notice the **event** property passed as parameter of the function added into the second row.

for old IE ver `attachEvent()` has to be used;

```
div.attachEvent("onclick", function(event){test(event, this)});
```

Notice that **attachEvent** has been replaced in modern standard js with **addEventListener** and now almost all modern browser support that.

Here
http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener
is possible to see compatibility table.