# JavaScript reference to event, declared by addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I am trying to implement a Web Application which is supposed to let you draw shapes over a grid of pixels. For this purpose, I need to add several event listeners to each table element of my grid.
This is what I did so far:

```
td.addEventListener("click", setpixel);
td.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    mousedown = true;
})
td.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    mousedown = false;
})
td.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    if (mousedown) {
        setpixel(?);
    }
});
```

The setPixel() function needs an event passed as parameter:

```
function setpixel(event) {
    var oldColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    var currentColor=document.getElementById("current-color").style.backgroundColor;
    if (brushwidth > 1 && brushwidth < 4) {
        brushpixel(this.id, offset, currentColor);
    }
    else if (brushwidth == 4) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "url('https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/design/2013/04/Susan-Kare-fill-icon-660x660.jpg')";
        floodfill(this.id, currentColor, oldColor);
        preview();
    }
    else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
    }
    preview();
}
```

Otherwise it cannot function properly.
Where do I get the referenced event from?

Linked thread does not work for me here, not sure why, but I tried it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding event as parameter within function, using addEventListener (Doesn't work in FF/IE). Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394750/adding-event-as-parameter-within-function-using-addeventlistener-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the click event to the table and make a condition to which your function will work exclusively with `<td>`. Use `e.target` to determine which `<td>` was actually clicked. Read this article on [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm). Started this answer before your edit so wasn't aware of new additions.

### Demo

```js
// Reference table#T
var T = document.querySelector('#T');

/* Register the click event on #T
|| setPixel() is the callback
*/
T.addEventListener("click", setPixel);


function setPixel(e) {
  /* e.target is the clicked element
  || If the clicked element is a <td>...
  */
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "TD") {
    /* ...if the td does not have a red 
    || background then make it red
    */
    if (tgt.style.background !== 'red') {
      e.target.style.background = 'red';
    } else {
      /* Otherwise make it black */
      e.target.style.background = 'black';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#T {
  width: 90%
}

table,
td {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<table id='T'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the event to your listening function arguments

```
td.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (mousedown) {
        setpixel(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that already. The setpixel function will throw: "undefined is not an object" when evaluating the passed event

Comment: post your setPixel function as well then

Comment: what are you trying to access with `this` in the setPixel function

Comment: "this" references the DOM element which called the function setpixel()

Comment: where are you evaluating the event in setPixel there is no ref to event which leads me to believe thats not whats throwing the error